# No notifications during the night hours

Tags: notifications, vibration, silent-mode

I had juice defender installed on my phone for a few weeks but then I decided to remove it. One of the settings that I set up was to disable the vibration and sound notifications during the night (from 0:30 to 6:30 or something like that). Anyway, now that the juice defender is removed from my phone this settings still remain. I am not completely sure it's like that because of JD, but I don't see any other reason for such behavior.

I tried installing juice defender again, disabled all these options, but the settings are still there and I still don't get any sound or vibration during the night hours. Did anyone else had such a problem? How could I fix this and restore these settings to the "default behavior"?

I am using CM 7.1.0 stable (Android 2.3.7) if that helps anyhow.

Comment: What apps/methods have you tested for notifications? Is the phone in silent mode at night, or does the ringer/notification volume appear normal but non-functional?

Comment: I'd check in `Settings->CyanogenMod Settings->Sound->Quiet Hours` to see if that's been turned on.

Comment: @eldarerathis - thanks, that did it. would you mind putting that as an answer so I could wrap this one up?

Comment: Done. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to check `Settings->CyanogenMod Settings->Sound->Quiet Hours` and make sure that it's disabled. That's been an unknowing culprit for me in the past.